# Material-UI - TextField - select text programmatically

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Material-UI V1 beta.

Could not find the answer in the [Docs](https://material-ui-next.com/api/text-field/#textfield).
How do I select text of a TextField component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a ref to it, then call the value of the ref. Something like this:

```
<TextField ref="myTextField" />

// Call this in the component that contains the text field so 'this' is set properly
function getTextFieldValue() {
    return this.refs.myTextField.getValue();
}
```

This is known as an uncontrolled react component. An alternative would be to use a controlled component and save the value in your state. Here is some info on the difference between controlled and uncontrolled components: https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Comment: Since the question is asking about selecting the right implementation should be return this.refs.myTextField.select();

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a stateless functional component then you can use react hooks.

Also make sure you are using inputRef

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

let MyFunctional = props => {
  let textInput = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(textInput.current.value);
          }, 100);
        }}
      >
        Focus TextField
      </Button>
      <TextField
        fullWidth
        required
        inputRef={textInput}
        name="firstName"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter Your First Name"
        label="First Name"
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```